# How to use Exiftool to copy jpg metadata to RAW file after exporting from Lightroom

Tags: exiftool

Using Lightroom, I made adjustments to some jpg files (primarily to the toning), as well as added some IPTC data. I saved the metadata to those files and also exported them.

Now I would like to copy just the IPTC and edit adjustments from either the sorce jpgs or the exported jpgs into their corresponding RAW files, but I'm not sure of the syntax or tags to specify.

This is my folder structure:

```
.\Working
.\Working\RAW_Source\
.\Working\JPG_Source\
.\Working\JPG_Exports\
```

Notes:

1. all file names are the same except for their extensions.
2. there are no sidecar files involved. Metadata needs to exist ONLY in the jpg
   or RAW files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the files have the same base name, your basic command would be along these lines.
To copy from `JPG_Source` to `RAW_Source`
`exiftool -TagsFromFile .\Working\JPG_Source\%f.jpg -xmp:all -iptc:all .\Working\RAW_Source\`

To copy from `JPG_Exports` to `RAW_Source`
`exiftool -TagsFromFile .\Working\JPG_Exports\%f.jpg -xmp:all -iptc:all .\Working\RAW_Source\`

To copy tags from either source (latter DIR has priority)
`exiftool -TagsFromFile .\Working\JPG_Exports\%f.jpg -xmp:all -iptc:all -TagsFromFile .\Working\JPG_Source\%f.jpg -xmp:all -iptc:all .\Working\RAW_Source\`

That will copy all XMP tags (which includes IPTC Core) and IPTC IIM/Legacy tags to the RAW files.

These commands would create backup files which can be suppressed with the [`-Overwrite_Original` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original).  You can recurse into subdirectories with the [`-r` (recurse) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse).

These commands do not include any GPS tags or EXIF tags. You can add the GPS tags by adding `-GPS:All` to the command.  It's usually not a good idea to edit tags in the EXIF group in RAW files unless you know exactly what you are doing, as it can cause the RAW file to become unviewable, as some of these tags are needed to tell software how to render the image (see [ExifTool FAQ #8](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q8)).

Also take note that these command write the data directly into the RAW file.  If you wish to write the data into an XMP sidecar file, the command would be more complex, depending upon whether the XMP sidecar files already exists or not.  If the sidecar files already exist, then you would add `-ext XMP` to the above commands.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks! I'm editing the question to address possible ambiguities.

Comment: Ok, then any of the above commands should work.  I only mentioned the sidecar files because I've seen some cases where people actually wanted the sidecar files edited and not the RAW.  Make sure and test carefully first before processing all the files.