# Synchronise EXIF data from RAW media to customized media

Tags: exiftool

I have an Insta360 X3 camera and I'm looking for a way to copy EXIF data from the RAW source 360 files to exported files (screenshots and custom animations). The problem is that the filenames are not identical. When saving a screenshot the original filename gets a postfix:

Photos:
c:\source\IMG_20230725_104331_00_006.insp
c:\target\IMG_20230725_104331_00_006_2023-08-12_17-46-48_screenshot.jpg

So ExifTool should take EXIF from source file and apply to target file(s) that match first part of filename.

Video:
c:\source\VID_20230728_113247_00_060.insv
c:\target\VID_20230728_113247_00_060_animation_preset1.mp4

I tried the ExifToolGUI, but that will allow me to copy one by one and I would like to process entire folder.

From a commandline, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326937/how-to-use-exiftool-to-copy-jpg-metadata-to-raw-file-after-exporting-from-lightr/59327683), but using identical filenames.

Can ExifTool do this operation? I can't find anything in the readme resembling this scenario. Any help with the required cmdline is appreciated.

Comment: Learned in the meantime that I can use the date time information from the filename to update the EXIF data using: exiftool "-AllDates<Filename" "PATH", which is already very helpful, but other EXIF information would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original filename is always 26 characters long excluding the extension, you could try

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile c:\source\%26f.insv -All:All c:\target\
```

Using the [`-TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT), for every file in finds in `c:\target\`, exiftool will look for a file in `c:\source\` which has the same first 26 characters of the filename `%26f` and a `.insv` extension.  It will then copy all the data it can to the target file, keeping them in the **exact** same locations (`-All:All`).  Note that this is different from using `-All` or not including any tag names as that might change the data's location.  See [exiftool FAQ #9](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q9)

See the "Advanced features" section of the [`-w` (`-TextOut`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut) for details on the percent tokens `%f`.

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.